# Device Orientation results in flipped node location

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

My code is very simple.  I want to change the positioning of an SKSpriteNode to always remain in the bottom right corner of the device screen.  I call my UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification method "rotated" on device rotation and it should simply move the node, but for some reason it always flips the desired location so the landscape position is where the portrait should be and vice-versa.

My code is as follows:

UI

```
    - (void)rotated:(NSNotification *)notification {
            DeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
            if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !_isShowingLandscapeView)
                [self.node setPosition:bottom_right];
                _isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
            }
            else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) && _isShowingLandscapeView)
            {
                [self.node setPosition:bottom_right];
                _isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is deviceOrientation coming from?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, but it was included in my code.  The problem remains, any suggestions?  In fact I shouldn't even need to check if it's landscape or portrait, I should just be able to specific the bottom right corner, but I've just trying this out.  The issue is that when I specify the bottom right corner it doesn't appear, period.

Comment: How are you calculating bottom_right?

Comment: CGSizeMake( self.size.width/2 - btn_wd/2, btn_ht/2 - self.size.height/2);      The anchor for my nodes and scene is at the center.  That's why I calculate it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I'm doing is simple. Just use UIButtons over your SKScene.  Go back to the UIViewController where you call your skscene from and add buttons.  You'll have to use NSNotification center to pass information to the buttons, labels, etc.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8843